# php page image links not working with MAMP

Tags: php, mamp

I'm running a php website locally using mamp.  On the front page (i.e. index.php) there are a few broken image links that point to image files like '/images/logo.gif'.  These were working on a version of the site hosted remotely.

In the actual main web folder I see a subfolder "resources" that contains the subfolder "images".  I can't figure out whether the image links should know to look in the resources folder from other code or if the img src field in the html (from inspect element on the locally hosted version) should actually be reading 'resources/images/logo.gif'.  I'm hesitant to just change the field in the code without knowing if it should be seeing the subfolder in resources.

EX.

```
-/site
-index.php
-/includes
-/resources
    ...
    -/images
        -logo.gif
        ...
-/css
etc....
```

I apologize for this novice question, but I just can't figure out the appropriate resources to find the right answer for this.

Comment: What is your webroot? `c:\mamp\htdocs`? (Or whatever it would be on a Mac.) In other words, your path's are going to be relative to that folder. If it's `/htdocs/resources/images/`, your URL would probably be `http://localhost/resources/images/`.

Comment: what is the site structure on the remote site?

Comment: I'm assuming the site structure is identical to the remote site, because the files were given in a bundle as the final version by the contractor that built it.  This is strange though, because it asks the question of why the subfolder /images could be referenced directly as /images and not Resources/images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your image links to "images/logo.gif" then your browser will look for the images folder in your root directory. The reason that you're getting broken image links is because you don't actually have an images folder there! You'll need to change everything to "resources/images/logo.gif".

Comment: That's what I thought, but it does work on the remote site.  You try looking at it at [link](http://thexenses.com), although of course the file hierarchy isn't necessarily visible.

Comment: Ahh.. it actually is visible.  the image linke on the front refers to images/logo.gif, but you can see that images itself is in the resources folder available at [link](http://thexenses.com/resources)

Comment: Well, looks like there's an images folder too at http://www.thexenses.com/images.  Looks like some weird redundancy thing.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it looks like on the remote site there were actually two separate images folders, one at the root level, and one in the resources folder.  That would explain my confusion.